Accessing source code of an original work open source licensed
In open source licenses, there are different requirements regarding the original work and the derivative one.
While I understand that for some permissive licenses, there is not a requirement to provide the modified source code, so as to allow releasing the software under a proprietary license, I can't understand how for the original work, the software author can release only a binary form without sources (such as MIT and probably other ones).
As open source license, freedom of studying the code and modifying it should be ensured; but when the software author does not provide an access to it, this freedom becomes unsatisfiable.
If this is right, how the modification freedom may be ensured?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

You ask about a case wherein an author writes a novel piece of software (without any components licensed from other authors), and then chooses to share it under a permissive license like MIT/X11 or BSD, but releases only the binaries without source code.
Certainly, such a release without source code cannot be called "open source" under the OSI's definition, in particular because such a release fails section 2 of the Open Source Definition ("Source Code").
This action might cause a little confusion -- i.e., by using a license most commonly employed for open source programs, but under a not-open-source arrangement that doesn't actually offer source code -- but I see no legal obstacle to releasing such a binary under permissive terms. I understand your question is predicated on a theory of law such that the act of freely granting rights, some of which can't be practically employed by recipients, might somehow legally obviate the grant at large, or could somehow impose obligations on the rightsholder to make conditions possible for recipients to employ that right.
But in this case here, we don't need to resolve this question at all, because it doesn't apply: the right to modify the binary can be meaningfully employed even without source code. Via binary editing with a hex editor and other decompilation tools, you can easily change strings, constants, and (with more effort) even behavior. You can produce reverse-engineered source code, which you are free to distribute, clean up, and modify. The author has surrendered their ability to forbid such derivatives (which, in general, they could forbid under copyright law) when they offered the binary under a permissive license like MIT/X11. I'm this way, we can see a license to modify a binary-only distribution is hardly useless.
This practical usefulness doesn't make such a no-source distribution "open source" by any means, but nevertheless, it has many real applications (and seems, to my mind, far from legally void).

One case I have seen where "binary-only open source" releases have been legitimate are some retro computing releases, where the actual source was lost long ago, but the right to decompile the binary is valuable.

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.
